# Login redirect back to question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login

Often when I'm browsing stackoverflow I am not logged in (say I've just been led here by a Google search). I then decide I want to upvote a particularly helpful answer, so am of course prompted to login. This action takes me to another page away from the question, and does not redirect back even after the login is successfully completed.

This behaviour makes it difficult to find the question/answer that I wanted to upvote; I either have to search on google or search on stack exchange.

Am I just missing a trick or could this behaviour be improved?

---

Here is the workflow I used:

- Click on upvote
- Click on "Sign up using Stack Exchange" (which isn't what I *mean* to do, but is what I intuitively click on)
- Click on the login tab (this is where the `returnUrl` parameter is lost)
- Login with my credentials

Comment: Why aren't you logged in when you get here from a google search? Are you always using a new computer?

Comment: If you’re using Firefox, you can right-click the browser’s back button and easily find that page again. I’m sure Chrome supports this as well…

Comment: I generally auto clear cookies on browser close. Security conscious or just paranoid idk.

Comment: Who cares why the OP is not logged in? Or that you can use the back button? It's just good design to bring someone back to what they were looking at after they elevate their credentials rather than sending them to a generic landing page. Do you have actual arguments about why the current design is better or this shouldn't be implemented?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I don't think asking that is wrong for the sake of discussion. That being said, I do agree that it is better user experience that, after a successful login, the user be redirected back from whence they came.

Comment: @TimLewis I don't see how the top two comments are promoting _on-topic_ discussion at all. This is about a UX problem, and a subsequent feature request to fix it. The first comment is just wondering aloud why anyone uses the site this way (OP does, I do, presumably others do), and the second one presents a simple workaround that should not be necessary. It's the exact annoyance that should be fixed.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist If I'm not mistaken, whenever you hit the login button, it  appends a `returnurl` parameter, to which after you succesfully log in, takes you back to the question.

Comment: Confirming what Braiam suggested, I just tested in an incognito window (Chrome on windows 7, clicked from google to an SO question, clicked to upvote, logged in via google) and got redirected, so maybe the OP and the alchemist (who apparently repro'd this) are hitting a bug. Either that or the steps I took don't map to what these folks are doing...?

Comment: Actually @Braiam your comment forced me to slow down and realize exactly what mistake I was making. When I hit the login widget I automatically click on "Sign up with StackExchange" because it's what I click on the normal login page. However, instead of doing the normal AJAXy thing and letting me log in (or sign up, since that's what I clicked -- I know, users don't read anything), it redirects me to the sign up page. It's there, when I switch the tab to log in, that I lose the returnurl parameter. I can confirm it works just the same as Frank for me in several other cases.

Comment: I have to admit, I was doing exactly the same, so I can only apologise. I just saw the 3 options on the popup (stackex/goog/Facebook) and assumed they were the login links, not sign up links. I should have slowed down a little....

Comment: Given multiple people made the same mistake, I do wonder if the login popup screen could be made more obvious.

Comment: @fpghost Actually that is possible in Chrome, just press and hold on the back button for a list of pages in the back-history.

Comment: @fpghost Note that when you already have an account, the signup and login forms actually work very similarly (signup will simply log you in). Now, it would probably makes sense for `returnurl` not to be lost when you happen to click on the login tab, which would redirect you to the question even if you don't take the time to read! :) (disclaimer: I work here, but this is only my opinion, and I don't know whether this is do-able).

Comment: Even better imo would just be for the whole login process to occur in the popup window in the foreground, whilst the question remains in the background (login form submitted with some AJAX), but maybe that is too ambitious.

Comment: Every time I'm logged out this happens. And every time it's because 'sign up' is far more prominent than 'sign in'. Every. Single. Time.

Comment: @abligh I agree. This is in fact the main problem, signup is too prominent

Comment: @fpghost or 'sign-in' is insufficiently prominent!

Comment: Not working for editing posts... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363805/login-redirects

Answer (score 4):

Good news! We've updated the way login works to ensure that the `returnurl` isn't lost when you change between the signup and login tabs. [Kevin Montrose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose) is to thank for this change.

This will ensure that you get redirected to the question you were trying to upvote regardless of how you sign in.

Obviously, this was a simpler change than changing the login process (to e.g. use AJAX). I'll tag this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for now, but keep your other suggestions in mind for the future.

Thanks for the report!

---

Note: this change isn't live as of writing this answer, but it should be soon.

Comment: Hey I have seen you from a quite [long time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31340289/4099593). But I had never seen the diamond! Have I been blind or did you get hired recently?

Comment: Hey @BhargavRao — you haven't been blind: I joined a few weeks ago! Hope you're doing well by the way, I remember you from the Python tag too ; )

Comment: Wow. Congrats. I did not read a blog bout you joining the dev team on blog.se. So I got confused. All the best for your new job! (and also do not forget [tag:python] ;) )

Comment: As I can see this problem was solved, but I face a bit different one, had to work with some WYSIWYG editor, so had to clear cookie from browser after all internal update, every time after this action, when I was back on stack I was not logged in (normal behavior I guess) and I click on the top of the page to login and was all the time redirect to my developer story after successful login. Is it a bug or I have some problems?