# Editing Posts Login Redirect

Tags: feature-request, bug

Every now and then, I Google an answer on programming. I find an answer on Stack Overflow, and try edit the answer. It asks me to login to have your modifications passed, so I do. It then redirects me to the user homepage, instead of the question. It'd be better if the login redirected the user back to the question. I currently have to find the answer again or go press back multiple times and refresh to edit a question.

How to reproduce:

1. Make sure all Stack Exchange accounts are signed out
2. Search for a question on Google
3. Open question and click `improve this answer`
4. Click `login to edit` (`returnurl` is lost here)
5. Login with credentials
6. Back to Stack Overflow landing screen

Comment: Agreed. But in the meantime you could also just stay logged in.

Comment: I'm using Firefox w/ max protection: It logs me out of everything and clears cookies after session ends. Different from InPrivate though. InPrivate does not accept cookies, not allowing me to login to my Gmail.

Comment: Maybe, if you know you're not logged in, you could open the login form in a new tab. Then you'll only need to F5 the original tab to leave your comment without sacrificing your security and privacy settings

Comment: @versvs That's what I do when I occasionally have to log back in.

Comment: I'm completely confused. If this is *not* the current behavior, how can it be a duplicate of a [tag:status-completed] question? Has the user encountered some kind of bug?

Comment: Okay, so I just tried in a browser I don't normally use, and it *looks* like the `returnurl` is set when I click "add comment." Can you provide your browser and steps to reproduce and edit your question into a bug report? I'll happily cast a reopen vote if you can do that.

Comment: Search something on Google. Ex: `__init__ on Python`. Then open a question and edit the post. On the top it says: `You are not logged in`. When you click on that, it redirects you to the login page, but with no `returnurl`.